# How to upload multiple PDF files to server using alamofire? #Swift 4 #IOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

How to upload multiple PDF files to server using third party library in swift 4 ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557938/ios-swift-uploading-pdf-file-with-alamofire-multipart

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS Swift uploading PDF file with Alamofire (Multipart)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557938/ios-swift-uploading-pdf-file-with-alamofire-multipart)

Comment: use DisPatchQue

Answer (score 0):

```
func uploadPDF() {
var pdfData = Data()
var fname = ""
var mimetype = ""
let url = URL(string: "https://myurl.com/api/attachment/upload")
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Authorization": "my Authorization Token",
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]

    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
           for n in 0..<self.array.count{
                pdfData = self.array[n].data
                if self.array[n].type == "image"{
                    fname = "pdfDocuments\(n)"
                    mimetype = "application/pdf"
                }else{
                    fname = "video\(n).mp4"
                    mimetype = "video/mp4"
                }
                multipartFormData.append(Data, withName: "files[\(n)]", fileName: fname, mimeType:mimetype)
            }


    },
      to: url!, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
        switch result{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in

                print("uploding: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
            })


            upload.responseJSON{ response in
                print(response)
                self.hud.dismiss()

                if let err = response.error{
                    print(err)
                    return
                }

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
    }
}
```